# Swipe text when you click on one of the images

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to do this with jquery so when you hover or click on one of the images (red boxes) the grey area (text area) changes to show the text related to that image. Adding class to execute display block doesn't work because I don't know how to link a specific image to a specific text area.

I tried to do it via toggling the not active class with the active class but again I don't know how to link the image to the specific text area. Here is a sketch picture of how it would look like.  [image: Hover on image to display a different text.]

The reason they are in 2 different grids it's becuase on a smaller screen only the first grid displays.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row py-5">
    <div class="grid-reviews">
      <img class="photothumb review-1" src="img/reviews/person1.jpg">
      <img class="photothumb review-2" src="img/reviews/person2.jpg">
      <img class="photothumb review-3" src="img/reviews/person3.jpg">
      <img class="photothumb review-4" src="img/reviews/person4.jpg">
      <img class="photothumb review-5" src="img/reviews/person5.jpg">
      <img class="photothumb review-6" src="img/reviews/person6.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-reviews-2">
      <img class="photothumb review-7" src="img/reviews/person7.jpg">
      <img class="photothumb review-8" src="img/reviews/person8.jpg">
      <img class="photothumb review-9" src="img/reviews/person9.jpg">
      <img class="photothumb review-10" src="img/reviews/person10.jpg">
      <img class="photothumb review-11" src="img/reviews/person11.jpg">
      <img class="photothumb review-12" src="img/reviews/person12.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="testimony-desc text-center">
    <div class="review-1 not-active">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A ab deleniti, deserunt dolorum et eum iure labore libero molestiae nam nisi nostrum obcaecati perferendis rem sed tempora vel velit veniam.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, cupiditate deleniti dolore et sit veniam! Beatae explicabo iure natus veritatis? Aliquam fugiat modi molestias nisi repellendus rerum sunt tenetur veniam!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci alias aspernatur debitis deleniti hic illo iure pariatur provident, quibusdam rem reprehenderit sit, vel. Eum nesciunt quaerat, ratione sed similique voluptas.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-2 not-active">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur eius eos inventore iusto laborum nostrum similique tempore veniam? Ipsa ipsum libero minima nostrum reiciendis. Ipsum iure laudantium nobis odit veritatis!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus nihil obcaecati voluptatem. Aliquid, blanditiis dolorem et harum ipsam magnam, nemo nesciunt obcaecati pariatur quaerat quisquam similique tempore velit! Numquam, perspiciatis.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis eligendi et hic illo in necessitatibus officia pariatur porro repellat! Ab alias amet dolor doloremque inventore, placeat qui quo rerum tempore.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis eligendi et hic illo in necessitatibus officia pariatur porro repellat! Ab alias amet dolor doloremque inventore, placeat qui quo rerum tempore.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis eligendi et hic illo in necessitatibus officia pariatur porro repellat! Ab alias amet dolor doloremque inventore, placeat qui quo rerum tempore.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-3 not-active">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-4 not-active">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-5 not-active">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-6 not-active">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-7 not-active">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-8 not-active">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-9 not-active">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-10 not-active">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-11 not-active">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="review-12 not-active">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      </di
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#wb_Image3 a img').hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: .4
        }, 200);
        $('.text').removeClass('hide');
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
        $('.text').addClass('hide');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/TwNGw/2/

check the fiddle link, it's a good demo of linking the image to the text area.

Comment: So for each image would I have to create a different id and then add another line of jquery to hover on that image to display the text? Or would this work dynamically

Comment: You have to add image url in the html with same class and the text you want to show, it will work .

Comment: I am still a little bit confused. My pictures and texts are separated by two different containers. If I hover on the first image it has the class of review-1 and so does the text that it is linked to it. So do I add an image url to the text as well? Or do I say that if you hover on review-1 then remove the hide class on image-1? 
I'm sorry I'm just really confused.